# Hibernate how to deal with multiple entity relationships?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a project with this data structure:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="users", cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
        public List<Project> projects;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @ManyToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    public List<User> users;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="project", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
public List<Report> reports;

}

@Entity
public class Report {
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid")
    public Project project;
}
```

How do I write my DAOs to avoid using one DAO within another? Specifically, if I need a method:

```
public void createUserReport(int userId) {
}
```

to identify which user created the report, I use the userId attribute. Should this method now belong to UserDAO, or to ReportDAO? Common sense tells me it would be the latter, everyone looking to create a Report would look inside ReportDAO. But if it was in the former, I can only use one DAO to create the report and update the user, cascading the updates down to the Report.
In the latter a separate UserDAO instance would be needed to create the relationship with the Report, not to mention the intermediate Project entity.

A simpler example:

```
public List<Project> getUserProjects(int userId) {
}
```

Returns Project objects, but if placed in ProjectDAO it would require a use of a separate DAO to first get the User object. Placed in UserDAO it becomes more resources friendly, but makes less sense.

Comment: Do you know Spring Data JPA project? It might solve a lot of your problems. http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Why would you need a separate UserDAO to find projects by user ID? Why would you need one to create a report? The DAOs have access the the EntityManager. They just need to use it to get a reference to a User (if necessary). Side note: I would really, really avoid making your associations EAGER: every time you will load a user, just to display its name for example, that will also load all its projects and all the reports of all its projects. You really don't want that.

Comment: @jb-nizet because I either use getUser(int userId) which belongs to UserDAO (bad - multitple DAOs) or repeat the code already used there (bad - code repetition) or write complex SQL queries (bad - cause it's not "Hibernate way" [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339446/how-to-handle-join-query-in-hibernate-and-spring-with-annotations)

Comment: The JPA way is to write JPQL queries, not SQL queries. Either accept a User rather than a userId as argument, and let the caller use the UserDAO (that you will need anyway), or just use em.find() or em.getReference() to get the user. That is just one trivial method call. It doesn't qualify as code duplication.